Magento 2 : Widget and Components Created for a PDP page
I have created a widget which is intended to be used for add information as a best seller, this is a category with this name, which has subcategories and products added to these. To display the data I need it to be displayed exactly as it does in my PDP, is it possible to use the existing elements to display data in my PDP but add them to my new widget? any advice for this please?

clearify in some more details.
